# Uninstall Previous XCode and Install XCode 4.5

Tags: xcode, xcode4.2, xcode4.5

Is it safe to completely uninstall previous version of XCode and Install the XCode 4.5? because...

I just uninstalled XCode 4.2, and it mostly removed all the files in the Developer Folder, now I installed the 4.5, but it scares me since there is nothing in the Developer Folder. 
Would XCode still be working even if that's the case? Thanks

Comment: Did you read the release notes?

Comment: though i heard from the wwdc that they're gonna bundle it, but just like to confirm, since the developer folder is empty, i'm just not use to it

Comment: I've added a link to the Xcode 4.5 release notes to my answer. It's handy reading.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Xcode 4.4+ was designed to be installed via the App Store and now stores everything in the Xcode.app bundle in your /Applications directory.

Make sure you use `xcode-select` to select the new path for your Xcode installation, and you install the command line tools from within Xcode 4.5.

From the [Xcode 4.5 release notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001051-SW174):

> Starting in Xcode 4.3, the Xcode.app file package contains all the Xcode developer tools. The man pages for the command-line tools Xcode uses are also placed in this package.

Answer (score 3):

yes It's totally safe to completely uninstall the previous Xcode and install new Xcode4.5. I have done it and all works fine for me.

Just have to install the command line tools after installing the Xcode4.5 from it's preference just as show in below image :)

[image]